# Where does set come from in "val Singleton4 : Set = set => set == 4"?

Tags: scala

What's the verbose way for `val Singleton4 : Set = set => set == 4`? I am unable to understand where the `set` parameter is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "coming" from anywhere, `Set` is defined as a function from an integer to a boolean and the type of `Singleton4` is exactly that, it takes an integer and returns a function which needs another integer and returns a boolean:

```
scala>   type Set = Int => Boolean
defined type alias Set

scala>   def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = set => set == elem
singletonSet: (elem: Int)Int => Boolean

scala>   val p: Set = singletonSet(3)
p: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

So now `p` is a function which takes an integer:

```
scala>   p(3)
res0: Boolean = true

scala>   p(2)
res1: Boolean = false
```

An alternative way of writing that is this:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int) =  (i: Int) => i == elem
val p: (Int) => Boolean = singletonSet(3)
```

Or using a different way but achieving the same result:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int)(i: Int): Boolean = i == elem
val p: (Int) => Boolean = singletonSet2(3)
```

By currying the function and applying only one argument you get back a function which still needs another integer to be fully evaluated.

Comment: what does the left hand of the assignment mean in "val p: (Int) => Boolean = singletonSet2(3)" I never seen syntax like val p:...

Comment: `val p: (Int) => Boolean` means `p` is a function which takes an integer and returns a boolean, if you have ever worked with collections and used fold, map, reduce and so on, check their signature, they all take some function from a generic type `A` and return a generic type `B` which in scala syntax is written `f: A => B`, this is the definition for `map` without some noise: `def map[B, That](f: A => B)`

Answer (score 3):

What maybe confuses you is the fact that `Set` is not what one would expect from the Scala library. You should read the line as:

```
val Singleton4:   Int => Boolean = someArbitraryName => someArbitraryName == 4
//  <identifier>  <type>         = <argument>        => <returnValue>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are very good, but I thought I'd throw some additional details to help newcomers to Scala understand the notation better (as there are some hidden gems in the notation that were not uncovered/described).

Let's play the Scala compiler game!

The following `val` says enough about what `Set` the type represents.

```
val Singleton4: Set = set => set == 4
```

The type of `val` is given explicitly - it's `Set`. We don't however know much about it...yet. It has however to be given to the compiler before it can be used and given the left-hand side it's a function (mind the `=>` two-letter string) from a type (we'll get to it in a moment) to `Boolean` since `set == 4` will inevitably end as `Boolean`.

From `set == 4` we can deduce that `set` can only be `Int` (so you can compare *apples* to *apples*) and hence we've got the type of `set` as `Int`.

The right-hand side of `=` of the `val` could also have been written as:

```
val Singleton4: Set = (set: Int) => set == 4
```

So, the `Singleton4` val is an instance of a function `Int => Boolean` that's called `Set`. `Set`'s declared as such somewhere above (lexicographically):

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

You could substitute `Set` to the type alias and end up with:

```
val Singleton4: Int => Boolean = (set: Int) => set == 4
```